# batch file: extract substring between two strings with special characters

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I get confused with the Windows batch way to process string and substring when it contains special characters.

From a script I obtained this variable:

```
echo "%longString"
```

which returns me:

```
"<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="more" href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">Download</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">64-Bit Graphical Installer (462 MB)</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86.exe">32-Bit Graphical Installer (410 MB)</a></p></div>"
```

And the only part that I am interested in is between `a href="` and `">64-Bit Graphical`.

Then, using this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018439/extract-substring-between-2-strings) (but I does not contain the difficulty of special characters), I tried many combinations of the proposed solutions but every time I get unexpected result with my case because of the special characters.

I thing that a non-working example could be

```
@ECHO OFF

:: define the longstring
Call Set "longString=<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="more" href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">Download</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">64-Bit Graphical Installer (462 MB)</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86.exe">32-Bit Graphical Installer (410 MB)</a></p></div>"

:: Define subtrings token
Set "subsA=a href=""
Set "subsB=>64-Bit Graphical"

:: Remove part before subsA
Call set "Result=%%longString:*%subsA%=%%"
:: extract part to remove behind subsB
Call set "Remove=%%Result:*%subsB%=%%"
:: remove part behind subsB
Call set "Result=%%Result:%Remove%=%%"

Echo "%Result%"
```

For now my best result is using `Set "subsA=href"`and `Set "subsB=64-Bit"` (so it is simpler since there is no special characters in), which allows me to go through the first settings of `Result` and `Remove` but then because these new variables contain many special characters the last setting of `Result` gives me crap.

I also tried to use `For /F` and `findstr` but the results where even worse.

So I eager to find any solution or/and explanations.

Comment: Is there any character that is not allowed to appear in your string? like `|`, for example?

Comment: @aschipfl yes I saw some ´|´ in my strings.

Comment: I meant in the portion that you want to extract, not the whole string?

Comment: @aschipfl Since the portion that I want to extract is an url address, as far as I know yes it can also contains character not allowed by batch files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `call` with special characters, it only gets worse ( in this case even CALL works, but thats only luck).

```
Set "longString=<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="more" href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">Download</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">64-Bit Graphical Installer (462 MB)</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86.exe">32-Bit Graphical Installer (410 MB)</a></p></div>"
```

Better use delayed expansion, as the results of delayed expansion are safe for all characters.

Even the first part fails

```
:: Define subtrings token
Set "subsA=a href=""
:: Remove part before subsA
set "Result=!longString:*%subsA%=!"
```

The problem is here the equal sign in subA `a href="`, the first equal sign is used as the delimiter in the `search=replace` expression.
It's better to change your search string to only `Set "subsA=a href"`.

Now you have more or less the correct string, the first two charcters can simply removed by `set result=!result:~2!`

Your idea to remove the tail of the string is good, but doesn't work in batch, you got again problems with equal signs in the `REMOVE` string.

But you could simply count the length of your remove string, that length can be used to remove it from the result by position.
But the length in remove_len is too short, because the length of subsB itself is missing.

```
set "remove=!result:*%subsB%=!"
call :strlen remove_len remove
set "result=!result:~0,-%remove_len%!"

echo !result!
```

To get the strlen, you could use a function like [SO:How do you get the string length in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5841587/463115)

The resulting code looks like

```
@echo off
setlocal
Set "longString=<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="more" href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">Download</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">64-Bit Graphical Installer (462 MB)</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86.exe">32-Bit Graphical Installer (410 MB)</a></p></div>"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: Define subtrings token
Set "subsA=a href"
Set "subsB=>64-Bit Graphical"

:: Remove part before subsA
set "Result=!longString:*%subsA%=!"
set "Result=!result:~2!"
set result
set "remove=!result:*%subsB%=!"
set remove
call :strlen remove_len remove
call :strlen subsB_len subsB
set /a remove_len+=subsB_len+1
set "result=!result:~0,-%remove_len%!"

echo !result!
   exit /b


:strlen <resultVar> <stringVar>
(   
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (set^ tmp=!%~2!)
    if defined tmp (
        set "len=1"
        for %%P in (4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1) do (
            if "!tmp:~%%P,1!" NEQ "" ( 
                set /a "len+=%%P"
                set "tmp=!tmp:~%%P!"
            )
        )
    ) ELSE (
        set len=0
    )
)
( 
    endlocal
    set "%~1=%len%"
    exit /b
)
```

Comment: I also thought about the index position but not the length. Your solution is efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you are trying to extract a URL which should usually not contain quotation marks on its own you could do the following:

- split off everything up to and including `a href="` (I intentionally removed `="` from this search string in order to be able to use [sub-string substitution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html), because the `=` separates search and replace strings);
- split the remaining string at `"` characters and extract the second part (the first part is `=`);

Here is a possible solution:

```cmd
@echo off

Set "longString=<p style="text-align: center;"><a class="more" href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">Download</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href=" https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe">64-Bit Graphical Installer (462 MB)</a></p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86.exe">32-Bit Graphical Installer (410 MB)</a></p></div>"

rem // Use delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `"` and other special characters:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem // Split off everything up to and including `a href`, then extract the second token in between `""`:
for /F tokens^=1^,2^ delims^=^"^ eol^=^" %%I in ("!longString:*a href=!") do (
    endlocal
    rem // Check for leading `=`-sign (could be skipped if not needed):
    if not "%%I"=="=" >&2 echo ERROR!& goto :EOF
    rem // Remove leading whitespaces:
    for /F "tokens=* eol= " %%K in ("%%J") do set "partString=%%K"
)
rem // Return extracted URL:
echo/%partString%
```